# RRAS Site-to-Site VPN Issues When Behind Edge Devices

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras, site-to-site-vpn

I have two networks I would like to bridge using PPTP using Windows Server 2008 R2 on both ends.

Network A is 10.150/16 subnet without DHCP available

Network B is 192.168.150/24 subnet with DHCP available

The RRAS server on 10.150 net is behind a hardware router and has full WAN access.

The RRAS server on 192.168.150 net is behind a NAT device, so it is the calling end of the tunnel.

10.150 net RRAS server assigns client IPs in the pool 10.150.200.10-20

192.168.150 net RRAS server assigns client IPs using the DHCP range of its LAN

(not sure if this is correct ^)

10.150 net RRAS has static IPv4 route to 192.168.150/24 through the tunnel

192.168.150 net RRAS has static IPv4 route to 10.150/16 through the tunnel

Hardware routers/NAT on both networks have routes to the other network set up to point to their local RRAS server.

I am able to successfully establish a tunnel but I am unable to ping/traceroute anywhere. My question is mainly regarding the IP addressing above. I have a feeling I need to switch the ip address assignments around, but I am lost at this stage.

Comment: Do you have LAN routing enabled on both RRAS servers?

Comment: Yes it was enabled.

Comment: Can you post the output of a tracert from a client on one network to an ip address on the other?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so turns out that Microsoft's definition of a site-to-site VPN involves 2 RRAS servers chatting to each other and ignoring their respective LAN clients.

My solution was partially obtained using this concept of a hub-spoke model:

http://aleyshon.blogspot.com/2013/04/site-to-site-vpn-with-windows-server.html

The secret sauce is in setting static IPv4 addresses on the demand-dial interface network settings to an IP in the respective destination subnet and adding routes like this:

10.150/16 has a RRAS server @ 10.150.0.10 and has a demand dial interface with static IP assigned as 192.168.150.128.

192.168.150/24 has a RRAS server @ 192.168.150.10 and has its demand dial interface with static IP assigned as 10.150.0.128.

This effectively disables the DHCP/IP pool assignment mechanism, making that a non-issue now.

Routes:

RRAS @ 10.150.0.10: route add 192.168.150.128 mask 255.255.255.255 10.150.0.128 -p

RRAS @ 192.168.150.10: route add 10.150.0.128 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.150.128 -p

This fixed bi-directional traffic and I am now able to traceroute/ping to and from servers on the LANs.

Microsoft really needs to look at simplifying the deployment of site-to-site where both RRAS servers are behind edge devices.